# Save Android emoji from Firebase to MySQL using Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, firebase, yii, yii2

I try to import data from `Firebase` into `MySQL` database.

My Firebase data looks like this:

[image]

Now, I try to get this record and save to MySQL:

```
$model = new DbModel();
$wpath = "/messages/". $id;
$wvalue = $firebase->get($wpath);

$wjson = json_decode($wvalue, true);            
$model->message = $wjson["message"]; //this is ok, if I print it'll show the emoji
$model->save();
```

After I save the model, I get this in my database:

```
I'm going to dance ????
```

I set `utf8mb4_general_ci` collation for my column in the table, and that seem to **work** when I insert the same text manually via script or UI, however the emoji is not saving when I save my model via php.

My Server version: `10.1.16-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution`

Web server: `Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/7.0.9`

Any advise would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Finally found a solution [here](http://andy-carter.com/blog/saving-emoticons-unicode-from-twitter-to-a-mysql-database)
It was important to change charset in db connection settings as well:

```
'components' => [
    'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
```